# How to use VBA to copy 5 sheets paste to 1 new workbook by appending

Tags: security

I am a beginner of VBA. I try to copy 5 sheets paste into 1 workbook named "Import". Each sheet contains about 1000-2000 rows and I want to append 5 sheets in "Import" sheet.

The problem is this needs to do every week and every time rows of each sheet varies. I don't know how to use VBA to get this done.

Thanks for attention and help.

Aladin